# Issue with multiplication by a fraction in pre-processor Substitution (#define)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, fractions

I'd like to start with the code

```
#define myConst (419*0.9)
#define myConst1 (419*.9)
#define myConst9 (myConst1*.9)
#define myConst11 (419*1.1)

int main()
{
    printf("myConst:%d\n",myConst);
    printf("myConst1:%d\n",myConst1);
    printf("myConst9:%d\n",myConst9);
    printf("myConst11:%d\n",myConst11);
    return 0;
}
```

Which gave me the output as

> myConst:1913895624
>   myConst1:1
>   myConst9:1
>   myConst11:1

I'm unaware about why multiplication by a fraction in #define is leading to a different value than expected? And also the value of myConst is varying continuously for example, some value I observed are **-254802840** **-1713343480** **466029496**. And also **myConst1**,**myConst9** and **myConst11** are giving me 1, which isn't logical according to me.

Any explanation regarding the same is most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#define` has no role in this; the problem is that you are passing a `double` when `printf` is expecting an `int` (due to the `%d` specifier); technically that is undefined behavior, so anything is allowed to happen.

Now, if this was built on 32 bit x86 probably you would get an `int` reinterpretation of the lower 32 bits of you float, since all parameters are normally passed on the stack. But I guess this is running on 64 bit x86, where parameters are passed in different registers if they are floating point. In this case, `printf` is just reading whatever garbage happens to be in some register at this time, there's not much logic involved in those values.

Notice that almost any compiler can warn you about this kind of mismatch between format string and values actually passed. For gcc and clang I suggest you to enable this warning (`-Wformat`, included in `-Wall`, which you should *definitely* enable), and possibly mark it as an actual error (`-Werror=format`), as there's no legitimate reason to do a broken `printf` like this.

Comment: You're right. But the whole point started at a GEL file of CCS where I'm comparing a value in a condition 'if(TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_9<(t1+(P2-P1)*419+419-t2)<TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_11)' where TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_9 and TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_11 are '#define TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS (419*40)
#define TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_9 (TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS*.9)
#define TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_11 (TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS*1.1)' and middle part of condition resolved in to 16893 (which is int) and other two are double and from logs I can see the 16893 well in limits but need a type converted, any idea on this front.

Comment: even after converting them (t1, t2, t3, t4, P1, P2, P3, P4) to float, there is no use. CCS (Code Composer Studio) console output is __(t1+(P2-P1)*419+419-t2):16938.0
(TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_9):15084.0
(TIMER_TICS_FOR_100MS_11):18436.0__, which well lies in the range but it is not entering inside the if.

Comment: `a<b<c` does not do what you think it does... In C, it is interpreted as `(a<b)<c`, where `a<b` is 1 if a<b and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Yes, in my case a<b will return 1 and c (__18436.0__) is greater than 1, which should resolve to 1 finally. Note: This logic is in GEL script, which is C-like expression based language, I wonder if any limitation in it ?

Comment: Ops, I thought it was some kind of C IDE... Unfortunately I have no experience in GEL, so I cannot help you with that. If you have doubts specific to GEL you should open another question and tag it appropriately (the fact that the language is C-like isn't really relevant to obtain meaningful answers, especially on finer points like these).

Comment: Hey @Matteo, found out the issue, 1. The condition should be specified as **(a<b) && (b<c)** and 2. The type conversion need to performed if they're int (__as GEL is not giving any error/warning message about the same__). Thanks & appreciate your help.